# Can I mount git snapshots?

Tags: git, snapshot

In my system, a lot of machines regularly check out the latest version of the code in their home directory on a NAS, then do their thing.

Checking out is time consuming and creates duplication. It would be nice to mount a git snapshot and let the machine transparently work with it, as if it was a checkout.

How can I do that ?

I am currently using CVS but I would consider any version control system which has this capability. Git would be preferred.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "snapshot"? Also, `git` it a distrubuted system. Every "clone" is a complete repository.

Comment: By "snapshot" I mean a git commit in particular. When test A starts, then somebody commits, then test B starts, I want test A to work on the pre-commit snapshot and test B to work on the post-commit snapshot, without having 2 checkouts physically present in the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

If you say it creates duplication, maybe you're not doing it the right way. You don't have to clone the repository at each time, just update an existing repository.

If machines already have a clone of the repository, pull and checkout of the latest version is usually very cheap, and cannot be reduced.